# When is Aut(G) the symmetric group of an Aut(G)-invariant generating set?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-actions, automorphism-groups

Let $G$ be a group, $X$ a generating set of $G$. Suppose $X$ is $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$-invariant, i.e. $\sigma(X)\subseteq X$ for all $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. When is the restriction homomorphism 
$$ \begin{gathered}
\operatorname{Aut}(G) \to \operatorname{Sym}(X)\\
\sigma \mapsto \sigma|_X
\end{gathered}$$
an isomorphism?

**Example:** <strike>$A_4$ with $X=\{\text{3-cycles}\}$ satisfies the above properties.</strike> $C_2\times C_2$ works, and so do all cyclic groups of order up to 4 (Thanks [Jeremy Rickard](https://mathoverflow.net/users/22989/jeremy-rickard) for the correction). Are there any other examples?

Comment: I don't think $A_4$ is an example. Cyclic groups of order up to $4$ and $C_2\times C_2$ are.

Comment: @JeremyRickard $\operatorname{Aut}(A_4)=S_4$, and each automorphism takes takes 3-cycles to 3-cycles. See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group:A4#Endomorphisms_3

Comment: But there are eight $3$-cycles.

Comment: @JeremyRickard ... oops! You're right.

Comment: I think this would fit in the less focussed question of classifying finite groups for which the automorphism group is isomorphic to a symmetric group $Sym(n)$. They should be quite scarce. For instance, for $n\ge 5$, the inner automorphism group would be either trivial ($G$ abelian), or a symmetric or alternating group, which means that $G$ is a central extension of a symmetric or alternating group and central extensions of these groups are quite well understood.

Comment: Going back to the question, I think that for $n\ge 5$ there's nothing not abelian, because then every orbit of $Alt(n)$ on $Sym(n)-\{1\}$ has cardinal $>n$. Hence I guess that the answer for your question is a short finite list.

Comment: The cyclic group of order 6 is also an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $G$ abelian, the complete list is $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_4$, $C_6$ and $C_2\times C_2$.

Proof:
Suppose that $X$ contains a non-involution $x$. Then $x^{-1}\in X$ (since inversion in an automorphism of $G$) but then $\{x,x^{-1}\}$ is a block of size 2 for the action of Aut(G) on $X$ and thus $|X|=2$ and $X=\{x,x^{-1}\}$ and $G$ is cyclic. Since $X$ is $Aut(G)$-invariant, $G$ must have only two element of order $|G|$ and this happens only when $G$ is $C_3$, $C_4$ or $C_6$. We may thus assume that $G$ is generated by involutions and hence is an elementary abelian $2$-group. It's easy to check that $C_2^n$ has this property only for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

(I was assuming $G$ is finite, but the proof can probably be adapted.)

For $G$ nonabelian, I think the only example is $G=Sym(3)$ with $X$ the set of involutions. You could probably prove this following YCor's comments for example.